# Another word for agnostic when used to suggest independence through a lack of concern

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

As described [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12871/odd-use-of-agnostic), in technical domains agnostic can be used to describe a state of affairs where one thing doesn't care about the specifics of another thing it's related to.  For instance, in software engineering, one might speaking of a "platform-agnostic" solution.  This suggests that the solution need not have any information about the platform it is executing on to be a solution - it's a solution independent of the platform.  In the same way you can talk about things being "OS-agnostic" or "language-agnostic".

I'm suffering tip of the tongue phenomenon.  I think that there's another word that be used in these "X-agnostic" constructions that means specifically what agnostic is being used for here.  When I try to sound it out, however, my brain keeps jumping back to "agnostic" or to "ambivalent", which is also not the word I'm thinking of.

I think the word I'm thinking of can also be used to describe the relationship between a theory and a question if the theory is non-dispositional with regard to the answer to the question.  "My theory is X with regard to that question."

It's driving me crazy.  What's the word I'm thinking of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A term synonymous with *platform-agnostic* is *[platform-neutral](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_is_Java_known_as_platform-neutral_language_How_is_it_more_secure_than_other_languages)*.

Perhaps the word you're thinking of is *neutral*.

Comment: That's what I was trying to think of.

Answer (score 4):

You might also try:

> [***independent***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/independent) : not dependent; not depending or contingent upon something else for existence, operation, etc. .

The abstraction layer is *OS-independent*.

Comment: +1. ‘Platform-independent’ and ‘OS-independent’ are indeed both very common and current terms when describing software that is created for multiple platforms.

Answer (score 1):

apathetic?
indifferent?
blind?

Comment: Define irony: +1 indifferent.

Comment: It took me a while to get that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with *apathetic*.

To help illustrate the nuanced difference between apathetic and agnostic, I present you with [The Church of the Apathetic  Agnostic](http://www.apatheticagnostic.com/) ("We don't know, and we don't care")

Answer (score 0):

You could say *[platform promiscuous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promiscuous)*

> not restricted to one class, sort, or person : indiscriminate - *education … cheapened through the promiscuous distribution of diplomas — Norman Cousins*

Answer (score 0):

**Platform-independent**

Platform-independent is the term I know from having worked in Information Technology. It means that a solution will work across multiple platforms - ie is not ‘dependent on any particular platform’ - in order to work.

I’m putting it as an answer as ‘independent’ is only half the answer and ‘platform-independent’ appears only in a comment.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform-independent_model